How to pass parameters to an injected function
I've got following function being provided at the app level:
  provide('myProvidedFunction', (value) => {
     console.log(value)
  })

and it's being injected like this:
const providedFunction = inject('myProvidedFunction')

How do I pass a parameter to the myProvidedFunction upon injecting so that I get a console.log of that value?
I've tried this but it doesn't work:
const providedFunction = inject('myProvidedFunction', 'item value')


Can't you do providedFunction('item value')?

Rather than put the console.log(value) in the provide function, why not write it this way instead:
provide('myProvidedFunction', (value) => {
     return value
  })

Then access it in the child component like:
const providedFunction = inject('myProvidedFunction')

console.log(providedFunction("item value"))

